# Rails: Use development db for testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, mongodb, mongomapper

I'm currently developing an application with a really large existing database (> 10 GB, MongoDB with MongoMapper). Now I want to write some tests to ensure that my controllers are working correctly with the existing data in the database.
Therefore, I want to use the data that is already imported to the development db for my tests. But I don't want to import all the data into the test database each time I run the tests.

Is it possible to configure the test setup to use the development database WITHOUT dropping it each time?

thx,
tux

Comment: If you're working against this data, it's probably changing pretty often. That seems like an unreliable way to test. For MongoMapper I usually write tests that setup some test data, then cleans up at the end. This runs quite fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is of course technically possible to run test suit without dropping the database, however it is a default behavior for a reason ;)

What testing framework are you using?

For rspec it as simple as running

```
$ rspec spec
```

But take a note that if you accidentally run it using rake it will clear your development database (it is beceause `rake rspec` task has `rake db:test:prepare` as prerequisite)